# Can I perform operations on a character array and individual characters after passing by reference to another function?

Tags: c

I want to initialize a character array, then pass it to a function that parses command line arguments. I want this function to overwrite the character array to the input argument from the command line, then perform some syntactic checks on individual characters within that array.

I'm not showing the original code I've been working on, but I think I have a sample program to highlight what I'm struggling with

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

void changeArray(char **arr){
    printf("Array is %s\n",*arr);
    printf("This character is %c\n",*arr[0]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",*arr[1]); //segmentation fault here
    printf("This character is %c\n",arr[2]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",arr[3]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",arr[4]);
    *arr = "bingo";
    printf("Array is %s\n",*arr);
    printf("This character is %c\n",arr[0]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",arr[1]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",arr[2]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",arr[3]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",arr[4]);
}

int main(int argc, const char* argv[]){
    char *blah = "hello";
    printf("Array is %s\n",blah);
    printf("This character is %c\n",blah[0]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",blah[1]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",blah[2]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",blah[3]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",blah[4]);
    changeArray(&blah);
    printf("This character is %c\n",blah[0]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",blah[1]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",blah[2]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",blah[3]);
    printf("This character is %c\n",blah[4]);
    printf("Array is %s\n",blah);
    return 0;
}
```

This is the program output, the first index into the character array seems to print the letter 'h' like I would expect, but any other index causes me to go out of bounds:

```
Array is hello
This character is h
This character is e
This character is l
This character is l
This character is o
Array is hello
This character is h
Segmentation fault
```

Comment: Try `(*arr)[1]`

Comment: Or save yourself a lot of grief by declaring a local variable as `char *ptr = *arr;` and then use `ptr[0]`, `ptr[1]`, etc. Of course, you do need to keep the local variable up to date. So after `*arr = "bingo";` you need `ptr = *arr;` again.

Comment: Thanks! That seems to work for printf. Is this an operator precedence issue then? Dereferencing the address has to come before indexing into the array? It sort of makes sense to do that first now that I think about it.

Is there some reason it wouldn't work for say string compare also? I have something like this in my original code: strcmp((*bus_device_func)[4],":")

Comment: `(*bus_device_func)[4]` is a single character, not a string. So the comparison is `if ((*bus_device_func)[4] == ':')`

Comment: Perfect, thanks! That clears up the confusion I had. My original code is now doing what I intended.

Comment: To be honest, the fact that you seem to need this syntax indicates that the software has a deeper design flaw. It might be worthwhile to discuss this with a colleague or classmate to see if you can come up with a cleaner solution.

Comment: It's very possible what I've come up with so far is suboptimal. I do plan on getting some feedback. In a nutshell, I'm trying to write a program that can run either on a host system or on a processor down on the pci device in the same way, talking to things also on the pci device.

It seemed like asking for the pci device's bdf as an input to the program for when it runs over pci was a natural thing to do. This syntax is just meant to catch if the user typos the usual format of the bdf…. would you do something differently? BDF format is XXXX:XX:XX.X where X is [0-9a-f]

Comment: So you're going to get a BDF, check the BDF, and potentially change the BDF? If so, the two possible approaches are to modify the BDF that's passed to the function, or create and return a new BDF. What I'm not understanding is why you need to change the caller's pointer directly.

Comment: We're getting a little off-topic. The best thing to do is accept one of the answers. Then put together a working example that shows how you intend to process the BDF, and post it on [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a problem with the order of operations.  Operator precedence states that the `[]` operation occurs before the pointer is dereferenced, so you've essentially advanced to the second pointer in an array of character pointers, and then dereferenced the first item.  You want to run `(*arr)[1]` to treat `arr` as a pointer to an array, rather than an array of pointers.

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence

Answer (score 1):

The precedence of the array subscript operator (`[]`) is higher than that of the pointer dereference operator (`*`). So `*arr[1]` is equivalent to `*(arr[1])`. But `arr` only has a single element (it's just the address of `blah`), so `arr[1]` isn't a valid thing to access (let alone to dereference).

To achieve what you want, you'll either have to use parentheses (`(*arr)[1]`) or use a subscript operator instead of a dereference operator for the top-level dereference (`arr[0][1]`).